# Unable to resolve Dependecy Android Studio

Tags: android, module, dependencies

I have a problem on building my project.
I got this errors:

Thanks for your help :D

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 0s
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':uhabits-android@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: uhabits-android

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':uhabits-android@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: uhabits-android

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':uhabits-android@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: uhabits-android

Answer (score 0):

add below dependency in app  module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'}
```

And use

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```